# Print even numbers form 1 il 100 and extract 3 in python

Tags: python, loops, events, printing, numbers

Hey I have a python exercise I have to solve.
Print all even numbers from 1 to 100 but skip 24, 38 and you age (22). How do I do that ?

I  have done this so far :

```
start, end = 1, 100

 for num in range(start, end + 1):
  
if num % 2 == 0:
    print(num, end = " ")
```

But now I don't know how to extract like specific numbers

Comment: add some more details. like what you have tried so far and what you want to achive

Answer (score 1):

The `continue` keyword should help.
Here is an example.

```
for i in range(10):
    if i==2 or i==4:
        continue
    print(i,end=' ')
```

Output:
`0 1 3 5 6 7 8 9`

This example should clear up your doubt. For more information on continue you can check the official documentation of python.
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops

Answer (score 1):

The answer Veeraja already gave works. But some other optimized way to do this would be:

```py
numbers_to_avoid = [24, 38, 22]
for i in range(2, 100 + 1, 2):
    if i in numbers_to_avoid:
        continue
    print(i, end=' ')
```

This works because the `range` method can have up to 3 arguments `(start, end, steps)`. You already know about `start` and `end` but `steps` tells to `range` the separation between the numbers it gives as result. So if you start in an even number and set `steps` to `2`, you'll have all the even numbers lower than `end`. Try this and comment.

Comment: Anytime. I'm the guy for the noob questions, hehe.

Comment: yeah, I have just started my first semester with programming, so still have no clue about anything :D